# Sort an array of arrays based on another array

Tags: javascript

How can I sort an array of arrays based on another array?

Example:

```js
const dataset = [
  [ 'red', [{name: 'Apple car'}] ], 
  [ 'blue', [{name: 'Toothpiece'}] ],
  [ 'orange', [{name: 'Sun'}] ],
  [ 'yellow', [{name: 'Cat'}] ], 
] 
const order = ['blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'orange']

const sortedDataset = sortArrayBasedOnAnother(dataset, order)
// [
//   [ 'blue', [{name: 'Toothpiece'}] ],
//   [ 'yellow', [{name: 'Cat'}] ],
//   [ 'red', [{name: 'Apple car'}] ], 
//   [ 'orange', [{name: 'Sun'}] ],
// ]
```

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```js
function sortArrayBasedOnAnother(dataset, order) {
  return order.filter((value) => dataset[0].includes(value))
}
```

Note: `dataset` is an array of arrays because it's computed from [groupBy of Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.sort()` can pass in a custom compare function then the custom function will check the positions of the elements in the second array and use that to determine the sorting order.

```
function sortArrayBasedOnAnother(dataset, order) {
  dataset.sort((a, b) => {
    let indexA = order.indexOf(a[0]);
    let indexB = order.indexOf(b[0]);
    return indexA - indexB; //will return negative, 0, or positive value depending on their positions inorder array
  });
  return dataset;
}
```

then calling the function with your dataset and order arrays and it will return the sorted dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I would try it like this:

```js
function sortArrayBasedOnAnother(dataset, order) {
  const colorIndexMap = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
    colorIndexMap[order[i]] = i;
  }

  dataset.sort((a, b) => colorIndexMap[a[0]] - colorIndexMap[b[0]]);
  return dataset;
}
```

The `colorIndexMap` maps the colors from the `order` array to their corresponding index positions. The `sort()` function expects a comparison function that takes two elements (`a` and `b`) from the array and returns a negative, zero, or positive value to determine the order. `colorIndexMap[a[0]]` retrieves the index position of the color in `a`, same with `b`. By subtracting these values, the comparison function determines the order: If the result is negative, it means that `a` should come before `b`. If it's positive,  `b` should come before `a`. If it's zero, the order remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `sort` method and then use `indexOf` or each element from the  `order` array to sort the `dataset`.

```js
const dataset = [
  [ 'red', [{name: 'Apple car'}] ], 
  [ 'blue', [{name: 'Toothpiece'}] ],
  [ 'orange', [{name: 'Sun'}] ],
  [ 'yellow', [{name: 'Cat'}] ], 
] 
const order = ['blue', 'yellow', 'red', 'orange']

dataset.sort(([a], [b]) => order.indexOf(a) - order.indexOf(b))

console.log(dataset)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a "key → item" map so that you can retrieve items by their keys, then iterate the `order` array and use that map to build the result:

```
const map = {};

for (let item of dataset) {
    map[item[0]] = item;
}

const result = [];

for (let key of order) {
    if (map[key]) {
        result.push(map[key]);
    }
}
```

(alternatively, for `map`, you may consider to use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object rather than a plain object)

Note that only items present in the `order` array will be included, i.e. if a key is missing from the `order` array, the corresponding item will not be included in the result.